# SSL3 Poodle issue with chrome on Mac OS

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Trying to get all my client side software patched for the Poodle SSL3 issue. I have patched Firefox easy enough but can't for the life of me find any info on how to remove SSL3 from Chrome on Mac OS.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be an easy way round this at the moment. For now you can open the AppleScript editor and add the following code:

```
do shell script "open -a 'Google Chrome' --args --ssl-version-min=tls1"
```

Then click 'compile' then File > Export, from the Export options, save the file as something like 'Google Chrome Poodle-proof' (it won't work if you give it the same name as the 'real' Chrome app) and choose 'Application' from the File Format drop down list.

You can then change the script's icon to the default Chrome icon, by going to the 'real' Chrome application, right clicking and choosing 'Show package contents' , then opening the file `Contents/Resources/app.icns` in preview. Copy the icon and then right click your compiled app and choose 'Get Info'. Click on the app's icon in the window that opens, then cmd+v to paste the new icon.

You can now remove the 'real' Chrome application from your dock, and replace it with your AppleScript.

Bit of a hack for now, but it works.